# What part of WCF handles Authentication?

Tags: wcf, authentication, cors

Written a self hosted WCF (4.5) REST service. Have CORS almost implemented correctly, but I am having problems because I need to support multiple Authentication methods, namely, Basic and Negotiate.

If I only add Basic and Negotiate to the ServiceAuthenticationBehavior, CORS won't work, because WCF will send 401 on the preflight OPTIONS requests.

If I add Anonymous, so that the ServiceAuthenticationBehavior will allow requests without Authentication, if I point a browser directly to the service, the browser does not prompt me for credentials.

What I need to do is to send 401's with WWW-Authenticate: Basic Negotiate, headers for all requests EXCEPT OPTION requests which are not authenticated.

The issue I'm having is that I have no idea which part of WCF handles that. Is it a WebServiceHost, a service behavior like WebHttpBehavior or is it the ServiceAuthenticationManager?

The MS documentation is horrible, ServiceAuthenticationManager is defined as "Represents a service authentication manager."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which part exactly does it. But if I were at your position and I'd want to find out then I would

**(1)** download and read (mainly by using a full text search tool) Microsoft's reference source. I would start by reading who uses the `ServiceAuthenticationManager` which you guess that it is the key term. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/ServiceAuthenticationManager.cs. If some important source code was not there I would use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to decompile and read contents of undocumented managed DLLs

**(2)** try to figure out what the WCF parts do by installing .NET framework debugging support into Visual Studio (using [MSDN: Visual Studio, How to: Debug .NET Framework Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc667410(v=vs.120).aspx)) and either

- F11 into .NET at places where my code would configure and instruct the WCF
- or put breakpoints at key parts of my code and once they trigger I would carefully study the call stack (and read the .NET framework sources around, why did the method get called and what could influence it, what are the other options visible in the source file)

**(3)** I would definitely configure WCF tracing and study captured logs. There is lots and lots of details about what is going on in the logs. Including key terms (class names, property names) for further inspection. ([MSDN: WCF- Configuring Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx))

**(4)** If the above steps would not work for me in a reasonable time-frame then I would login as Microsoft Windows developer to a site dedicated by Microsoft to Windows developers and I would ask the question there (you can find good candidate for the right "where" at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?sort=relevancedesc&brandIgnore=True&searchTerm=wcf)

So I don't know right now how exactly does the authentication layer work and how is it possible to plug-in another strategies. So I don't have a clear answer for you and if there was a simple tutorial for this use case I would gladly read it.

If you find the final answer, please share your know how somewhere (e.g. here or on your blog or as an article in the [Microsoft TechNet site under the WCF tag](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/Technet?query=wcf&beta=0&ac=4) linked from here) with the rest of us - programmers like you

I wrote this to give you some hints how you can catch the fish by yourself and to somehow disagree with your claim that "MS documentation is horrible" (**(1)** and **(3)** are my main counterarguments)